# Add setOnAction method to custom Scene Builder Control

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

So I followed [this blog](https://rterp.wordpress.com/2014/05/21/adding-custom-javafx-components-to-scene-builder-2-0/) ([part 2](https://rterp.wordpress.com/2014/07/28/adding-custom-javafx-component-to-scene-builder-2-0-part-2/) in particular) to create a custom control and import it into Scene Builder.

This is what it looks like:

[image: Custom control that holds a ArrayList]

Here is the fxml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<fx:root maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="150.0" type="AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" layoutX="-65.0" layoutY="-56.0" spacing="5.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="previousButton" minWidth="25.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="25.0" text="&lt;" />
            <Label fx:id="label" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" prefWidth="500.0" text="Label" />
            <Button fx:id="nextButton" minWidth="25.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="25.0" text="&gt;" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

Here is the class File:

```
package swipeselector;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

/**
 *
 * @author patrickb
 */
public class SwipeSelector extends AnchorPane {

    @FXML
    private Button previousButton;
    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private Button nextButton;

    ArrayList<String> items;
    int selectedIndex;
    private boolean repetitive;

    public SwipeSelector() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(
                getClass().getResource("swipeSelectorFXML.fxml"));

        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }

        items = new ArrayList<>();
        selectedIndex = 0;

        previousButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            setPrevious();
        });

        nextButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            setNext();
        });

    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<String> items) {
        this.items = items;
        selectFirst();
    }

    public void setPrevious() {
        updateItem(selectedIndex - 1);
    }

    public void setNext() {
        updateItem(selectedIndex + 1);
    }

    public void selectFirst() {
        updateItem(0);
    }

    private void selectLast() {
        updateItem(items.size() - 1);
    }

    private void updateItem() {
        if (items.isEmpty()) {
            label.setText("");
        } else {
            if (selectedIndex < 0) {
                if (repetitive) {
                    selectedIndex = items.size() - 1;
                } else {
                    selectedIndex = 0;
                }
            }
            if (selectedIndex >= items.size()) {
                if (repetitive) {
                    selectedIndex = 0;
                } else {
                    selectedIndex = items.size() - 1;
                }
            }
            label.setText(items.get(selectedIndex));
        }
    }

    private void updateItem(int selectedIndex) {
        this.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
        updateItem();
    }

    public void setRepetitive(boolean cyclesThrough) {
        this.repetitive = cyclesThrough;
    }

}
```

Everything works fine, BUT: When I click the next or previous button, I want something to happen in my original project. I would usually do this by adding a `setOnAction(new EventHandler ...` method to the object. This method does not exist though, so I somehow need to add this to my custom control. **How do I make my custom control invoke a ActionEvent every time one of the two buttons is clicked, and how do I create a setOnAction Method for my object that will work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make it work. The following code is added to the Class File (it is basically copied from ButtonBase.

```
public final ObjectProperty<EventHandler<ActionEvent>> onActionProperty() { return onAction; }
    public final void setOnAction(EventHandler<ActionEvent> value) { onActionProperty().set(value); }
    public final EventHandler<ActionEvent> getOnAction() { return onActionProperty().get(); }
    private ObjectProperty<EventHandler<ActionEvent>> onAction = new ObjectPropertyBase<EventHandler<ActionEvent>>() {
        @Override protected void invalidated() {
            setEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, get());
        }

        @Override
        public Object getBean() {
            return SwipeSelector.this;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "onAction";
        }
    };
```

Also, whenever something happens where you want that Action Event to be fired, invoking the method `fireEvent(new ActionEvent());` will do this for you. This method goes back to the Node Class, which is inherited to this class as it extends AnchorPane (which inherited the `fireEvent` method from Node).

So in my case, I replaced my two onAction methods for the two buttons I have by this:

```
previousButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            setPrevious();
            fireEvent(event);
        });

nextButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            setNext();
            fireEvent(event);
        });
```

Now, whenever one of the two buttons are pressed, an ActionEvent is fired (I just passed on the Buttons Event for this purpose) and I can catch that in my project by adding

```
swipeSelector.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println("Event fired!!!");
            //DO SOMETHING 
        });
```

as usual.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a custom event. Unfortunately, there is little information about this. You can have a look at the source code of ButtonBase to get a sample.

You'll need to define an onAction property:

```
ObjectProperty<EventHandler<ActionEvent>> onAction
```

I've implemented a utility class for this: [SimpleEventHandlerProperty](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-commons/current/docs/site/apidocs/org/drombler/commons/fx/event/SimpleEventHandlerProperty.html)

You can find a complete sample using SimpleEventHandlerProperty here: [LeftTestPane.java](https://github.com/Drombler/drombler-commons/blob/42ea276917df5a73f7fa43efb1b14004e529385a/drombler-commons-fx/drombler-commons-fx-samples/drombler-commons-fx-samples-docking/src/main/java/org/drombler/commons/fx/samples/docking/LeftTestPane.java)

You can get the library from Maven Central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drombler.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>drombler-commons-fx-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did look into the ButtonBase, but didn't understand how events are fired. Turns out this comes from the Node's fireEvent. I'll post my own answer as I've found a way to make it work, thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: @Maverick283 Yes, you need to call a method from Node. The SimpleEventHandlerProperty makes this easier as you don't need to implement a custom property subclass.

Comment: What you did there looks quite nice! I think though for now my solution will do for my purposes, but thanks for sharing.